No handler for double click on vscode.TreeItem
I need to handle double click on vscode.TreeItem but i did not find any.
I need separte handler for single click and double click
I have followed sample - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/main/tree-view-sample/src/testViewDragAndDrop.ts
Could anyone please let me know how to handle double click on vscode.TreeItem?
